# Adobe Air SDK 2.0-2.5 Errors

Tags: apache-flex, sdk, air

I downloaded the Air 2.5 SDK and get the following Errors:

1-Design mode could not load aircore.swc. It may be incompatible with this SDK, or invalid.

2-Design mode could not load applicationupdater_ui.swc. It may be incompatible with this SDK, or invalid.

3-Design mode could not load applicationupdater.swc. It may be incompatible with this SDK, or invalid.

I installed by copy pasting the new SDK into a copy of the 4.0 SDK
I'm using FlashBuilder4.  FYI: Also installed is FlashCS4 with the SWC extension.

Any idea on how I may fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to download the latest beta on FB4 to go along with the new SDK.